# POST method doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get value from jQuery, consider it a condition to store another value in to database.
Here's my jQuery code:

```
 $('#button').click(function () {
            var s;
            $.each($('#main li.' + set.select + ' a'), function (index, value) {
                s = $(this).attr('name');                   
                alert(s); 

                $.post('random.php',
                {
                    id:s
                })              
            });

        })
```

and I take this `s` to PHP:

```
$con=mysqli_connect(" ") ;


  $id=$_POST['s'] ;  

  if(substr($id,0,1)=='1'){
       $a = '24 june';
  }
  else if(substr($id,0,1)=='2'){
       $a = '25 june';
  }
  else if(substr($id,0,1)=='3'){
       $a = '26 june';
  }  
  else if(substr($id,0,1)=='4'){
       $a = '27 june';
  }
  else if(substr($id,0,1)=='5'){
       $a = '26 june';
  }
  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `comp1` SET `col1` ='Booked!' where Day = '$a' ");
```

My table has a column called 'Day', this column contains dates above
I can not update the data in the row, no matter what value of `s` is, the `name` is a number. I also tried using `toString` for `name`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

`$id=$_POST['s'] ;`  means your value name is `s`, but it is actaully `id`

you are also passing the `attr =NAME` from jQuery which isn't the `VALUE`

`s = $(this).attr('name');` means you are pulling the object's `name="string_here"`

so for example `<input type="text" name="inputforid" value="10"/>`

Will give you the value `inputforid` and what you want should be the value

so attr ("value") or the `.val()` function in jquery

Read here - http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: ok thank you, I got the first one, but I don't quite get the attr('name'), I think it is a string now so it can be passed

Comment: That is the way I did but it didn't work. Do you suggest any way to do this ? I just need to get the value of the attribute

Comment: well almost everything You need is provided there.. maybe your `$.post('random.php',` is pointing to the wrong place,

Comment: well, is there any chance that my substr doesn't work ? or the if...else

Comment: if your actually getting the ID value of the input then $id should be a single number. **YOU SHOULD ALWAYS** do testing via `echo $id;`

Comment: it seems the `$id=$_POST['s'];` is the problem. I changed it to a number then it worked. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: try reading my answer and example, that was already stated in there. you don't need substr and use a switch case statement for this.

Comment: just append to your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use $id=$_POST['s'], because parameter in your post request is id and s is value, so try
$id=$_POST['id']

And also s = $(this).attr('name'); is element which has attribute 'name'.